# Metamask duplicated actions

Tags: metamask

When I interact with my deployed smart contract (Ropsten testnet) on Chrome I sometimes face the following situation :

1. I call my method which is an approval of my contract

[image]

2. After confirming I get this second window which should not exist :

[image]

I can't click on "reject" or "confirm", the window is stuck.

I had this issue twice in 3 days. To fix it I had each time to reinstall Metamask. Then, all was working well again. 
Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: You may want to go ask metamask directly. Seems very specific to me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by just reseting the Metamask account which basically clear the transactions history in the chosen network. 
The issue was maybe related to a mismatching nonce of the transactions.